# How does HealthKit actually share data?

Tags: ios, share, healthkit

On the Apple's HealthKit Framework official site it says that 
"The HealthKit data is not saved to iCloud or synced across multiple devices. The data is only kept locally on the user’s device."

If it's stored locally and never synced with a cloud then it means that I cannot share it with other users. But then Apple says that it's possible to share your data with your doctors as Epic and Mayo clinic are Apple's partners. How is this possible? 
And also, how does the data come from wearable devices to the phone? 
It's very confusing.

I would be grateful if anyone could explain that because Apple and others basically say the same things and no one explains how that really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HealthKit is a data repository that apps from the App Store use to share health data.  The user may choose to authorize an app to read or write HealthKit data.  For example, an app from Withings can write weight measurements from its wireless scale to HealthKit and then Strava may read those weight measurements to keep your profile on their site up-to-date.  This is how apps share data using HealthKit.

Comment: So, this data repository is just on my phone. Can I share this data with other users? Is there such uniform mechanism in HealthKit? Thanks.

Comment: Sharing data with another user would be implemented by the app that stores or retrieves data in HealthKit.  There is no mechanism in the framework to facilitate that kind of sharing.